# Is there a good practice for when to use `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`?

Tags: parskip, vskip

Is there a (scientific) standard in articles or books for when to use `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`?

Comment: I think (opinion) that consistency of use is more important than the actual case-protocol adopted.

Comment: In an ideal situation you should not need to use any of them manually in your document. (I use them in macro definitions, but not in the text as I see that as an indicator that I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: as a general rule you should be avoiding adding _any_ explicit space. Your document class should be specifying spaces around captions, theorems, lists etc and so manual correction within the document should only very rarely be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, all suggestions are appreciated!